# Xamarin Forms Previewer Design Time Data

Tags: xamarin.forms

I try to setup design data so that they are shown in the Xamarin Forms Previewer. I have a DesignTimeViewModelLocator:

```
public static class DesignTimeViewModelLocator
{
    static DesignTimeAboutViewModel aboutVm;

    public static DesignTimeAboutViewModel AboutVm => aboutVm ?? (aboutVm = new DesignTimeAboutViewModel());
}
```

And a DesignTime View Model:

```
public class DesignTimeAboutViewModel : IAboutViewModel
    {
        public DesignTimeAboutViewModel()
        {
            Resources = new LocalizedResources(typeof(Strings), CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public LocalizedResources Resources { get; }
        public MvxAsyncCommand GoToWebsiteCommand { get; }
        public MvxAsyncCommand SendMailCommand { get; }
        public MvxCommand RateAppCommand { get; }
        public MvxAsyncCommand GoToRepositoryCommand { get; }
        public MvxAsyncCommand GoToTranslationProjectCommand { get; }
        public MvxAsyncCommand GoToDesignerTwitterAccountCommand { get; }
        public MvxAsyncCommand GoToContributionPageCommand { get; }
        public string Version { get; } = "0.4.5";
        public string Website { get; } = "www.foo.ch";
        public string SupportMail { get; } = "foo@me.ch";
    }
```

And in the Page:

```
xmlns:design="clr-namespace:MoneyFox.Presentation;assembly=MoneyFox.Presentation"
BindingContext="{x:Static design:DesignTimeViewModelLocator.AboutVm}"
```

But the view doesn't display anything that is not static, for example the version which works when I run the App:

[image]

Do I have to set this up differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out after some rebuilds and restarting VS this more or less works as expected:

[image]